# How to record an audio CD with track information in Brasero?

Tags: 18.04, audio-recording, brasero

I use the following process:

I select the tracks on my PC and add the files to Brasero. Brasero then burns the CD correctly but, when I play the CD in a commercial CDJ Pioneer or in another player not on my computer, the name of the track does not appear.

E.g. The Pioneer does not show the name of the artist or the title of the track and only shows "track 1, track 2.....).  When playing an .mp3 file it does show additional information though but for .wav or .aiff it doesn't. The audio files are original one, paid for and downloaded from beatport, traxsource, iTunes and similar sites.

*So how do I get the additional track information to display on the Pioneer?*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** What do you mean by "Record a CD"?  Create a new CD from existing tracks from multiple other CDs or copy an existing CD or ...

Comment: I want to burn a traditional audio CD (.wav or .aiff). I select the tracks in my pc, and I add the files to Brasero. Brasero burn the CD well but, when I play the cd, in a CDJ Pioneer or in another player, the name of the track does not appear, for example, does not show the name of the artist or the title of the track, only show "track 1, track 2.....) in mp3 yes it shows, but in .wav or .aiff no. The audio files are original, paid and downloaded from beatport, traxsource, itunes and similar sites.

Comment: i'm not 100% sure because i used this a long time ago, but if you talk about [**cd-text**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-Text) and the information of your *original files* is stored via common tags (vorbis-comment, ID3, etc.) - not in a separate database of your store - it may be pretty easy: just install [**`brasero-cdrkit`**](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/brasero-cdrkit) and you don't have to fiddle around with anything else... just put the **tagged original files** into brasero (after selecting audio-cd) and you're ready to burn.

Comment: I already have brasero-cdrkit installed, although I appreciate your help, I've already got (thanks to a partner of the forum), solve the problem I had with k3b permissions. But thanks also for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### <s>What you're trying to do is impossible.</s>

#### What you're trying to do is very difficult.

Your CDJ Pioneer player is a combination of CD / MP3 player that can extract the name of the tracks from the lossless information on the original CD or the MP3 files.  WAV files do not contain *any* information except audio and aiff is a proprietary Fruity format that requires Fruity licensing.

So you *could* convert the non-MP3 files to FLAC, create a CD Table of Contents using [CD-Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-Text) and then it'll work on any CD Player, ***but that's a lot of work!***

### But why do I get track information on my computer then?

Well, your computer is connected to the Internet and uses fingerprinting or has proprietary software (libraries) licensed by the Fruity company so yes, it can display what it *thinks* it is (and will get it wrong every now and then, though that is rare nowadays)

#### Is there something easier I *can do?*

Yes, you can convert all non-MP3 files to MP3 and manually add the missing information if said information is not available in the original file format (E.g. WAV) and your CD/MP3 player will just display the information from the MP3 file.  Have a look at [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).

ffmpeg can be installed using:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77361/discussion-between-fabby-and-melebius).